# Adding canonical tags in Magento (Pre 1.4)

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add canonical tags to specific pages in Magento. This has been well documented and fairly simple in recent additions of magento as they are supported. However, we run an old version of Magento in which it is not built in.

I have found many instructions most request that you add this to the page update layout.

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>http://www.AddYourUrlHere.com/</href>
</action>
</reference>
```

However, this causes and error (i think due to the version of magento) and the page fails to load. I am sure that there is a method to add them and it has been hinted to look at the head.phtml file.

Could anybody shed any light on this and help me find a fix for Magento 1.3.2.

I know handfuls of coding in php but thats about it so it would be apreciated if any answers were explained as if im an idiot :)

Thank you!

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addLinkRel(Array

(
    [0] => canonical
    [1] => http://www.AddYourUrlHere.com/
)
)
Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addLinkRel', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->addLinkRel('canonical',        'http://www.AddY...')
#2 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(338):   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204):  Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),  Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(200): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(303): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(85): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '69')
#8 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(376): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#9 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(248): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/atpinst/public_html/app/Mage.php(459): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/atpinst/public_html/index.php(67): Mage::run()
#13 {main}
```

Comment: can you paste the error?

Comment: I have edited the first post to include it. Sorry should have done to start with